# How to calculate custom fields in ArcGIS Reports?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, reports

I have a custom report in ArcGIS that summarizes my fields using basic descriptive statistics. For example, here is a summary field that calculates the maximum value in the group for a particular field:

[image]

What I would like to do is calculate the range (|max-min|). However, this function is not included in the summary statistics. I think that I can use the "Fields>Calculated" menu to add custom fields. Here is a screenshot of that:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of what has to go in as the "Formula" for the field calculation, and how do I fill out the element properties for the field I would like to populate with this calculation:

[image]

Comment: Have you seen the help page regarding calculating fields in reports?  It's light on information, but might help you get started.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004v0000001w000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recommended by @TimothyMichael I think you will need to follow the help page entitled **[Calculating fields in reports](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004v0000001w000000)** which advises:

> You can use Report Designer to create fields in your report that do
>   not exist in the data source. This is useful if you want to create a
>   dynamic field that is dependent on other attributes within the data
>   source. To create a dynamic field, you can use a C# expression to work
>   with string, date, or numeric field types.

If the issue is that you do not know how to write such a C# expression, then revise your Question to include that detail, and tag it with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) to hopefully attract an Answer from someone who can.