# How to Dynamically Calculate Fields in ArcGIS Report?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, c#, reports

I came across [How to calculate custom fields in ArcGIS Reports?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42230/how-to-calculate-custom-fields-in-arcgis-reports/) and it's very similar to what I'm trying to accomplish.  I have two fields that are sums and would like to divide them in order to get a percentage.

Based on the response, I'm assuming a C# expression is needed, but I haven't a clue how to write a C# expression.  I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction, or provide a general C# expression example using sum and/or divide...?

Based on the screenshot below, my expression would be something like: **sum(Field1) / sum(Field2)**
 --- green / red

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**As per doc**

> There are two ways to create calculated fields in the Report Designer.
>   The first method is to add a text box to the report and enter an
>   expression into the text box that will get executed when the report is
>   generated. The steps to this method are outlined below, including
>   expression examples. **The second method** is to add an **unbound** Calculated
>   field to the report. You can only do this from the Report Section
>   tree. Right-click on the Calculated node of the tree and choose Add.
>   This will create an unbound field that can be used in the report. The
>   expression of the unbound field should be set in the Formula property
>   of the field. Once the Formula is set, drag the field on to the
>   section in the report where you want to use it.
>
> Unbound fields allow you to use other unbound fields in the Formula.
>   As a result, you can create Summary fields that use unbound fields to
>   generate dynamic content in the report.

and at the end it says:

> You will not be able to use unbound calculated fields to calculate a
>   summary statistic that uses other summary statistics in the formula.

So the short answer is, It is **not possible** to do what you need. and it is related to the poor design of ArcGIS reporter generator!

Although there is not any Report tool to achieve this, there a workaround. Preprocess your data and add a new field (percents) to your table; use field calculator to calculate percents; then add a summary field(sum of percents / records count) in report designer.